# track eye by tracking.js

Tags: javascript, eye-tracking, tracking.js

I recently found recently the JavaScript library - [tracking.js](http://trackingjs.com/)

Is there any way to detect what `div` I see now by image or camera?

I have two elements on the desktop, the left and right columns, and I would like to check if I see left `div` ( with `console.log()` ) or right `div`. This library is simple, and I know how to add a script, but I don't know how to detect my eye and detect what element I see.

Maybe there are other ways to detect this.

Answer (score 2):

Thats a bit complicated because you need detect minimal ocular movements and the common webcams, haven't resolution enough, but with some hardware like this project http://pupil-labs.com/pupil/,  could do that.

A good solution is tracking.js because this library simulate human behavior with a some algorithms and should be enough to make simple decisions like the columns position.

Comment: I have a my device "camera hand-home-made" which perfect detect eye - a have a photo like this: http://up.programosy.pl/foto/tracking.png , any ideas ?